# Can i check if subsequence faster then O(n*n)

Tags: c#, .net, performance, algorithm, complexity-theory

So my question is in topic's name. Does exists an algorithm that checks if B is subsequence of A faster, than O(N^2), for example O(NlogN) or simply O(N)?

Only way found is simple brut-force

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.Length - b.Length; i++)
{
   if (IsSubsequence(a,b,i))
      return i;
}
return -1;
```

Comment: You should define subsequence and give an example to avoid confusion. Also add your code for `IsSubsequence` please

Comment: Because usually subsequence means something different from what you seem to ask

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a recursive characterization of David Eisenstat's algorithm. (Note that this algorithm is *tail recursive* and can therefore be written as a loop; I describe it as recursive because doing so is a nice way to understand the algorithm.)

Define a sequence as either empty, or an item followed by a sequence.

Take two sequences, A and B. The question is if B is or is not a subsequence of A.

If B is empty then B is a subsequence of A.

If B is not empty and A is empty then B is not a subsequence of A.

If we've made it this far, neither A nor B are empty.  Suppose that A is item X followed by sequence C and B is item Y followed by sequence D.

If X is the same as Y then the answer to the question "is B a subsequence of A?" is the same as the answer to the smaller question "is D a subsequence of C?".  Answer that question.

If X is not the same as Y then the answer to the question "is B a subsequence of A?" is the same as the answer to the smaller question "is B a subsequence of C?".  Answer that question.

This procedure terminates and clearly its worst case is in the length of the sequence A.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can be done faster than `O(n^2)` with an algorithm by [Knuth, Morris and Pratt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm#Efficiency_of_the_KMP_algorithm). However note that the implementation provided by the [framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) might already implement this algorithm.

Comment: Subsequence, not substring

Comment: I already changed the answer to link to the `Contains` method instead of the `Substring` method. Do you mean something completely different by 'subsequence'?

Comment: @Codor: Substrings are a special kind of subsequence. If you have the sequence "A, B, C, D, E" then "A, C, E" is a subsequence but not a substring. "B, C, D" is both a subsequence and a substring.  A substring has no "gaps". KMP finds substrings, not subsequences.

Comment: Thanks for youe remark, I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the following greedy algorithm is correct and runs in time O(n). For each element of B in order, scan forward in A from the previous stopping point (initially the beginning of A) for the first occurrence.

Comment: how you got O(n) when here we have two nested cycles?

Comment: @AlexJoukovsky They're nested because that's how one would implement them, but together, the inner loop accounts for at most one scan through A. You could think of them as being non-nested, with control flow pinging back and forth.