# What is the generic list equivalent of Strings.Contains?

Tags: c#

I have a method that searches for the longest matching substring within 2 strings. It does this by looping through:

```
myFirstString.contains(mySecondString.subset(i,j))
```

But what if instead, I want to find the longest matching sublist within 2 ordered lists? In other words, what if my arrays are not of characters, but of other objects?

What is List equivalent of ".contains" for strings?

`myFirstList.contains(mySecondList.getRange(i,j))` is incorrect, because `.contains` here is looking for an item, not a List.
`.Intersection()` only checks for matching items, not matching sublists of items.

(Ideally, I would like this method to be able to use List< T>, but List< myObject> will do.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can i check if subsequence faster then O(n\*n)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22637634/can-i-check-if-subsequence-faster-then-onn)

Comment: Edit: to clarify, I am looking for the equivalent of a _substring_ rather than a _subsequence_.  
If I have ABCA and ACAC, then I expect to return "CA" as the longest match, not "A...CA"

Comment: You said you were looking for `Contains` in which it accepts a sequence.  That means it's returning a boolean indicating whether or not that sequence is contained within another.  That's *exactly* what you asked for.

Comment: So... no, there is no List equivalent, I should just write my own implementation?
(The post appears to be fairly confused on the definition of 'subsequence' - I assumed it was not dealing with just substrings, sorry.)

Comment: does the answer work for you? or are you facing any other issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use an extended version of `Contains` that first tries to find the index of the first occurrence of the first element of `list2` inside `list1`. If it is found, then iterates up to the last occurrence of that first element of `list2` inside `list1`. If a match is found for any such index using `SequenceEqual`, the loop returns. Here is the `generic & extended` version of `Contains`:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static bool Contains<T>(this List<T> list1, List<T> list2)
    {
        int firstIndex = list1.IndexOf(list2.First());
        int lastIndex = list1.LastIndexOf(list2.First());

        if (firstIndex == -1) return false;

        for (int i = firstIndex; i <= lastIndex; i++)
        {
            if (list1.GetRange(i, list2.Count).SequenceEqual(list2)) return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

By the way, you must have to implement `IEquatable<T>` inside of class `T`.